# Media player mute doesn't make action

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to use a mute button inside my app as bellow :

```
ImageView muteMusic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.muteMusic);
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);


public void mute(View v) {

    switch (mAudioManager.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        break;

    }
}
```

XML

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/muteMusic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info"
            android:onClick="mute"
            android:src="@drawable/volbutton" />
```

but its not working , I dont know why ! no errors and no crashes ! but it does not make any action when I click on it

Comment: Try to add a log message after each of the calls to `setRingerMode` to make sure that this code is actually being executed.

Comment: @Zoltán both of them executed correctly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're muting the ***ringer*** instead of your music stream.

Instead of using

```
mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

use

```
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

Please refer to the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute%28int,%20boolean%29) for information on how to manage muting/unmuting within your application regarding releasing resources.

Comment: and how can i check if its mute or not ?

Comment: what is your application trying to accomplish apart from muting the media?

Answer (score 1):

you may use mediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0)